# How to insert data from MySQL into textarea when someone select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, tinymce

I need to insert data from MySQL into textarea when someone select option but page should not to refresh and it will be more options so every option will be for particular text, it should be something like this:

```
<select name='title_for_text'>
<option value='1'>Title 1</option>
<option value='2'>Title 2</option>
</select>

<textarea> SELECTED TEXT FOR TITLE 1 </textarea>
```

And when some select Title 1 It should show in textarea form mysql base text for document id 1...

I USE TINYMCE TEXTAREA...

Comment: did you search about that?? .. ok this link will help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef thanks it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Html:

```
<select id="select">
        <option value="1">Title 1</option>
        <option value="2">Title 2</option>
    </select>

<textarea id="textarea"> SELECTED TEXT FOR TITLE 1 </textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#select").on("change",function(){
    var SelVal = $(this).val();
    $.post("url\to\php",{SelVal:SelVal},function(answer){
        $("#textarea").val(answer);
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$val = $_POST['SelVal'];
$query_result='';
//Your Query Here
echo $query_result;
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you can go with:

```
function loadText(e) {
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    $('textarea').load('get_text.php?v='+thisValue);
};
$('select[name=title_for_text]').on('change', loadText);
```

In [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yusq620/).

This assumes your `get_text.php` script will output the text based on posted variable `v`.